# How to check in file in SharePoint using R?

Tags: xml, linux, curl

I am able to upload a file to SharePoint folder through a shiny app from a Rshiny server. However, I am not able to check in the file. Any advice please? I am not able to implement the suggestion provided here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341625/performing-multiple-requests-using-curl-with-different-options]. I am not able to dynamically update the node element value for the pageURL in the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.txt</pageUrl>
      <comment>Automagic update</comment>
      <checkinType>0</checkinType>
    </CheckInFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using R:

```
library(XML)
#put above xml in test.xml and pass on the path of this file to below xmlParseDoc()
xml_doc = xmlParseDoc("test.xml") 
invisible(replaceNodes(getNodeSet(xml_doc, "//ns:CheckInFile//ns:pageUrl/text()", c(ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"))[[1]], newXMLTextNode("YournewPageUrl")))
xml_doc
```

Comment: This works like a charm. However, end of the day I am not able to CheckInFile in the SharePoint after uploading it.  the curl commands runs without  throwing an error and that's it. I am saving the relevant xml file as out.xml and tried the following in vain.

curl --ntlm --user usrname:pwd -d @out.xml -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile"  -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" somesite.com/sites/site/Documents/folderX/filename.ext -k

Comment: And also this:

curl --ntlm --user usrname:pwd -d @out.xml -H "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckInFile" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"   somesite.com/sites/site/Documents/folderX/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx 

What am I muissing?